# Google Chrome Extensions - Open New Tab when clicking a toolbar icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I create an extension for Chrome that adds an icon to the toolbar, and when you click it, it opens a new tab with some local web page (for example: f.html)?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412258/chrome-extension-onclick-extension-icon-open-popup-html-in-new-tab), but it doesn't really explains what should I add in the manifest file...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is not true for newer chrome apps.

Newer chrome apps having manifest_version: 2
requires the tabs be opened as:

---

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

---

Comment: This is the better, more current and more accurate answer, FYI

Comment: @DehanWjiesekara Put it in e.g. background.js and have `"background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ] }` in your manifest.

Comment: will `tabs.create` fire when used in onInstalled in the context of loading an unpacked extension that basically just has a local index.html, and a background.js that right now purely opens the index.html in a new tab? for some reason that's not working for me right now, must be something simple im missing.

Comment: Just keep in mind that using a "tabs" permission will show the user a warning upon installation that the chrome extension needs to "Read your browsing history", but if you just wanna open a new tab then just use "activeTab" permission instead, it won't trigger that warning.

Comment: You had to do this, didn't you?

Comment: This is working fine but opening multiple tabs on subsequent clicks. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Note that for manifest V3, you need to use `action` instead, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216500/chrome-action-is-undefined-migrating-to-v3-manifest

Answer (score 55):

Well, in the [extensions docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html), it states in [manifest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html), you would need to include "tabs" as its permission. Same way they explain the hello world application:

**Manifest File:**

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Opens up a local webpage",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
  "background_page": "bg.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "",
    "default_icon": "icon_19.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
  ],
}
```

Within the [background page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), you listen to the mouse click event on the browser action.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('f.html')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
});
```

As you noticed above, you will see that I used the question you saw in the other post. Note, this isn't tested, but I believe it should work.

Comment: Beware that adding "tabs" permissions will show a "Read your browsing history" permission warning to the user on install. The docs say that most `chrome.tabs` don't require this permission https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs Because I didn't pay close attention to this, I recently lost hundreds of users from https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inbox-by-gmail-checker/mpjmeeikbbgccbjkbfabocnjcaejdpmj

Answer (score 8):

chrome.tabs.create need the permission of "tabs".

Simply using **window.open** in extension without need of any permission. and the code is shorter. I suggest this solution.

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Comment: i did use same code in my extension to open new tab on click of notification button . but now after 3 months i am getting aw..snap page error when clicking on that button. do you have any idea why this happened ? P.s : it works fine if i use another url like : www.google.com but it's not working with my site.

Comment: This seems to work for me (although I've only tried it in a local unbundled extension that I'm working on).