# Open new tab from chrome extension

Tags: json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanna create a chrome extension that when you click it that you open my website. But how?
I tried searching on google but this is all what I could create:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "The first extension that I made.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
        // Tab opened.
    });
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://api.flickr.com/"
  ]
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extensions - Open New Tab when clicking a toolbar icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188384/google-chrome-extensions-open-new-tab-when-clicking-a-toolbar-icon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit of code,

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
});
```

cannot be used directly in the manifest. If you look at the [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) for how to use browser actions, the correct way of handling the click event is to put something like this in the JavaScript on your background page:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {

    chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
        // Tab opened.
    });

});
```

From your manifest, it looks like you don't have a background page. Simply create an HTML file with some JavaScript in it, and reference it in the manifest like so:

```
"background_page" : "background.html"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{"manifest_version": 2,"name": "my app","version": "2.0","description": "This is a chrome extension for my app","browser_action": {"default_icon": "icon.png","default_popup": "popup.html"},"permissions": ["www.bibsoblog.blogspot.com"]}
```

If you want create a extention to go to your website by clicking the extension, and just use this code here [click this to add that code to your popup.html](http://www.instant-web-site-tools.com/html-redirect.html).