# Open new tab from Chrome Extension Context Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

UPDATE:
So because of the way my folder is structured, it looks like instead of `chrome-extension://meajimhgfmioppbkoppphhkbcmapfngh/index.html` it should be `chrome-extension://meajimhgfmioppbkoppphhkbcmapfngh/html/index.html`. When I type this in manually into the search bar it works but is still not working when I update my code to this:

```js
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (result) {
  if (result['menuItemId'] === 'open-sesame') {
    chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': chrome.extension.getURL("/html/index.html") }, function (tab) {
    })
  }
})
```

I have a chrome extension where users are presented my extension as a new tab. A new feature I am implementing is the ability to switch back to the default google search page and now users can access the extension from the browser action context menu. I referenced [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984399/open-new-tab-from-chrome-extension) when trying to come up with a solution.

I am now stuck at the contextMenu since when I click on it, I come up to the page where it says file could not be accessed.

`background.js`

```js
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title: "Open",
  contexts: ['browser_action'],
  id: 'open-sesame',

})

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (result) {
  if (result['menuItemId'] === 'open-sesame') {
    chrome.tabs.create({ 'url': chrome.extension.getURL("index.html") }, function (tab) {
    })
  }
})
```

The url that the new tab opens to is `chrome-extension://meajimhgfmioppbkoppphhkbcmapfngh/index.html` which seems like it would be correct to open my extension but it is still not working for whatever reason.

`Folder Structure`

html

- index.html

js

- background.js

css

- style.css

Comment: Sounds like your extension doesn't have `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to add the right file pathing to access my `index.html` and update the extension to get it to work.