# grab contents of textbox and go to URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple Google Chrome extension that produces a popup (HTML) when the icon is click. I want the user to be able to provide an ID number into the text box, and when clicking GO, the a new tab is opened and the user is taken to "http://www.staticURL.com/items/itemID=XXXXX" where the first part of the URL is unchanging, but the XXXXX is replaced with the textbox values.

So far I've been able to enter my function, but nothing happens when I click the button.

popup.html:

```
<html>  
    <body>
        <form method="post" name="idpopup" action="">

            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>HelpDesk ID Number</b></legend>
                <input type="text" id="idbox" size="25" maxlength="6" autofocus>          

                <input type="button" value="Go" id="gobutton"/>             
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

scripts.js:

```
function goHDLink(){   
    alert("goHDLink"); 
    //window.location = "http://www.staticURL.com/items/itemID="+document.getElementById("idbox").value;
}
document.querySelector('#gobutton').addEventListener('click', goHDLink);
```

So I get the popup, but no navigation to the URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem has anything to do with the extension.

```
window.location = "..."
```

Should be

```
window.location.replace("...");
```

OR

```
window.location.href = "...";
```

If it does have something to do with the extension it may be a permissions issue.  Check this question:

[Google Chrome Extensions - Open New Tab when clicking a toolbar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188384/google-chrome-extensions-open-new-tab-when-clicking-a-toolbar-icon)

Comment: sorry, no dice with either `window` line change or adding tabs to the manifest file. I also tried to just open `www.google.com` with that button, nothing happens....

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
window.open('http://www.staticURL.com/items/itemID='+document.getElementById("idbox").value,'_newtab');
```