# Chrome extension background page not adding new tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have written a sample extension to just add new tab to chrome in background page. It's not working. I am new to chrome extension, can you please help me?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "Test Extension.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
   "page": "bg.html"
   },

  "permissions": [
    "history",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

bg.html

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "www.google.com";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename `bg.html` to `bg.js` and change manifest background declaration like this

*manifest.json:*

```
  ...
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
  ...
```

*bg.js:*

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab)
{
    var newURL = "www.google.com";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am new to this. Can you help me as why was java script required? Why it didn't work with a simple html background page as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188384/google-chrome-extensions-open-new-tab-when-clicking-a-toolbar-icon

Comment: Inline javascript is not allowed in html background page. You can use script tag `<script src="bg.js"></script>` and keep your manifest declaration with `"page"`