# How do I open a new tab with URL in Google Chrome Extension on click? (with code example that i've)

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to open a new tab in Google Chrome Extension. I've simplified my test case to this HTML:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
```

Here's code that I've:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (activeTab) {
    var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
  });
});
```

I found the answer `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in this thread:

[Google Chrome Extensions - Open New Tab when clicking a toolbar icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188384/google-chrome-extensions-open-new-tab-when-clicking-a-toolbar-icon)

But this doesn't work when I click my link and I don't understand how to use `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` in my case.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to open a link in new tab on clicking extension icon or <a> element in your popup?? Please be more specific

Comment: @sid - Yes I'm trying to open a link in a new tab when clicking on <a> INSIDE of extension popup.

Comment: I found answer - will answer myself now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `popup.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click', 'a', function(){
     chrome.tabs.create({url: $(this).attr('href')});
     return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @sid - your answer works. Accepting as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add attribute `target="_blank"` to the links in your popup.html.

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer myself:

```
$('#link').click(function () {
  var newURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

No need for `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`.

Comment: Your code will always open this url not the one in href

Comment: Thanks @sid - you're right. But this also works if I know url in href already.

Comment: BTW, this happens because `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` [will not fire if the browser action has a popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked).