# How to create a new tab with default values?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

[In new tab create method](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) I see that all Parameters for `createProperties(object)` are marked "optional". But when I try

```
//if there is no storage create a new tab

var firstRun = (localStorage['firstRun'] == 'true') ;

if (!firstRun)
{
    chrome.tabs.create() 
    {
        console.log("new tab is created")   
    }
}
```

I get `Uncaught Error: Parameter 1 is required.`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412258/chrome-extension-onclick-extension-icon-open-popup-html-in-new-tab/2517348#2517348) to a similar question also appears to say that parameters are optional.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass an empty object:

```
chrome.tabs.create({});
```

The object is not optional, the values in it are.