# Open popup.html when click in extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I started studying javascript today and I'm trying to do a google chrome extension. I want to open a new tab with the main html (popup.html) when I click in the extension icon.

I'm having trouble with this because I changed it so much and keep poping up a hundred of new tabs.

Here's my manifest:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Youtube Autoplay",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Autoplay selected YouTube videos from my browser",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_title": "Youtube Autoplay",
        "default_icon": "icons/icon16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "tabs"
    ],
    "background":{
      "scripts": ["popup.js"]
    }
}
```

Here's the function that I'm using to open new tab

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
  // Tab opened.
});
```

I found some old awnsers here, tried some and still getting the problem.

Comment: When you are saying "I changed it so much and keep poping up a hundred of new tabs.", what do you mean? many tabs are opened? And what's your entire `popup.js`? I mean when `chrome.tabs.create` is called?

Comment: Yes, many tabs were open. I changed for what Sid said and now it's not opening a new tab, just a popup down the extension's button.

Answer (score 3):

Add an [onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked) listener on browser action(extension icon):

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(functiont(tab){
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')},function(tab) {
  // Tab opened. 
 });
})
```

**NOTE** :

onClicked listener will only run when extension does not have a popup. So remove `"default_popup": "popup.html"` from `manifest.json`. Also you need to add popup.html under web_accessible_resources  `"web_accessible_resources": ["popup.html"]`

Comment: Now, when I click in the button I get only a small screen from this, not a new tab.

Comment: @T.Borges Did you remove "default_popup": "popup.html" from manifest.json??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you also include `popup.js` in your `popup.html`, which means `popup.js` is referred by both event page and popup page.

When the event page is called after you installed the extension, it will call `chrome.tabs.create` to create a new tab with url `popup.html`, and `popup.html` will also call `chrome.tabs.create` because there is a `script` tag referring `popup.js` in `popup.html`. Then it will result in an indefinite loop and many tabs would be opened.

Considering you want to implement "clicking extension icon then opening a tab with popup.html", you could register `browserAction.onClicked` event listener in event page and call `chrome.tabs.create` to create the new tab. Sample code would  look like the following

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Youtube Autoplay",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Autoplay selected YouTube videos from my browser",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Youtube Autoplay"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html") });
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```