# Opening chrome extension in new tab when toolbar icon is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want the extension HTML to open in a new tab rather than in a popup. An existing extension, [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko?hl=en), has the exact behaviour that I'm looking to replicate.

The issue is that Chrome opens new extension tabs nonstop after I click on the toolbar icon, when the desired behaviour is (obviously) to have just one tab open. Strangely, I can get just one tab to open when I use a "web URL" such as https://stackoverflow.com/.

`manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "angular chrome extension boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "background"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

`background.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL('index.html') });
```

Several posts on this site have a similar question but none of the suggested solutions worked for me:

- [Chrome Extension: onclick extension icon, open popup.html in new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412258/chrome-extension-onclick-extension-icon-open-popup-html-in-new-tab/2413465): When I use event pages or add a listener to the `onClicked` even, nothing happens when I click the extension toolbar icon.

Comment: Put it inside a click listener for the icon: [sample](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/make_page_red/background.js).

Comment: The tab doesn't open if I put `chrome.tabs.create()` inside a click listener.

Comment: It's time to [debug the background script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the right way to get a tab to open upon clicking the toolbar icon is to wrap the call to `chrome.tabs.create()` in an `onClicked` listener:

Revised `background.js`:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL('index.html'), selected: true });
});
```

Initially this will not work due to `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` being `undefined`. To solve this, [one needs to add an empty `"browser_action"` object to `manifest.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42378697/4858387). Also, the previously used persistent background and `activeTab` permission are unnecessary and can be removed:

Revised `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "angular chrome extension boilerplate",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "browser_action": { },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "background"
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: This is working fine but opening multiple tabs on subsequent clicks. How can I prevent this?

Comment: The `selected` property is now deprecated. Use `active` instead. Also, the `chrome.extension.getURL()` function is deprecated and one should use `chrome.runtime.getURL()` instead.

Comment: Also, in Manifest V3, replace `chrome.browserAction` with `chrome.action`.